# How to Number a sequence block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the Sequence of numbers below, how can I assign a Sequence number so that each block which starts with a 1 and ends with a 0 is given a unique identifying number?  How can I create the Sequence Number column using TSQL?

| Sequence | SequenceNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |

Comment: Without a column that denotes the order of the rows to start with, it's impossible.

Comment: Do you have any column indicating the row order? A date, an ID, ...?

Comment: There is  DATETIME field for each row but they might have the same values

Comment: Can a sequence-0 row have the same datetime as a sequence-1 row? If, so, we wouldn't know whether the sequence-1 row belongs to the block before the zero or after.

Comment: *"they might have the same values"* Then it isn't helpful to denote if the row should be *before* or *after* another row.

Comment: I am able to add a unique ID to every row if that helps.

Comment: @planetmatt, add the CREATE TABLE DDL and sample data INSERT statements to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COUNT OVER` to count zeros. You need some column to determine the order. I am calling it sortkey in the following query:

```
select
  t.*,
  count(case when sequence = 0 then 1 end) 
    over (order by sortkey
          rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) + 1
    as sequence_number
from mytable t
order by sortkey;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/3DZBeDMQ